# Is there a way to restore VS2010 settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings

During uninstallation of VSDocman (documentation generation plugin), all my VS settings were reset, including carefully crafted keyboard shortcuts and windows placements. 
And I don't have any export of these settings (had to run backups, i know....)

Is there any way to get these back? or once they are gone, they are gone forever?

Thanks

**UPD:** I know, I accepted the answer, but I magically found the backed up settings in
`C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings\` in Windows 7. So before the settings were deleted, VS backed them up. Very happy with this -))

Thought might share this, for future searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once they're gone, they're gone forever.  After you set them up, it's probably worthwhile to export your settings to a safe place for future retrieval, or if you setup on a new machine.

Comment: one never sets up backup before the fail.. Will export now.

Comment: I have found the automatic backup in `C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings\` So not really gone forever -)